# How to specify outside of submatrix in a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a 1024x1024 image matrix A and 256x156 image matrix B. I want to set all of pixels to zero in A except for pixels where B = 1.

If B has the same size, I can just do

```
A(B~=1)=0;
```

But since B is of smaller size, I want to find complement of B in A. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could zero-fill B up to the same size

B(1024,1024) = 0;

And then your statement would work.

Answer (score 0):

should the centers of A and B overlap? if so then, you need to symmetrically Nan-pad B matrix with the function padarray.

if not then you may asymmetrically NaN-pad B.